# LINQ check list of objects contain a value AND not some other values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's say I have this list of objects:

```
var shipments = new List<ShipmentTracking>() {
    new ShipmentTracking() {
        trackingNumber = "32021001000", trackings = new List<Tracking>() {
            new Tracking() { trackingCode = "EBC", trackingPoint = "Entered", trackingDateTime = DateTime.Now, trackingMemo = "" }
        }
    },
    new ShipmentTracking() {
        trackingNumber = "32021001001", trackings = new List<Tracking>() {
            new Tracking() { trackingCode = "EBC", trackingPoint = "Entered", trackingDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), trackingMemo = "" },
            new Tracking() { trackingCode = "AWB", trackingPoint = "Registered", trackingDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), trackingMemo = "" }
        }
    },
    new ShipmentTracking() {
        trackingNumber = "32021001002", trackings = new List<Tracking>() {
            new Tracking() { trackingCode = "EBC", trackingPoint = "Entered", trackingDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), trackingMemo = "" },
            new Tracking() { trackingCode = "AWB", trackingPoint = "Registered", trackingDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), trackingMemo = "" },
            new Tracking() { trackingCode = "DSP", trackingPoint = "Shipped", trackingDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), trackingMemo = "" }
        }
    },
    new ShipmentTracking() {
        trackingNumber = "32021001003", trackings = new List<Tracking>() {
            new Tracking() { trackingCode = "EBC", trackingPoint = "Entered", trackingDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), trackingMemo = "" },
            new Tracking() { trackingCode = "AWB", trackingPoint = "Registered", trackingDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), trackingMemo = "" },
            new Tracking() { trackingCode = "DSP", trackingPoint = "Shipped", trackingDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), trackingMemo = "" },
            new Tracking() { trackingCode = "CCI", trackingPoint = "Cleared", trackingDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), trackingMemo = "" }
        }
    },
    new ShipmentTracking() {
        trackingNumber = "32021001004", trackings = new List<Tracking>() {
            new Tracking() { trackingCode = "EBC", trackingPoint = "Entered", trackingDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4), trackingMemo = "" },
            new Tracking() { trackingCode = "AWB", trackingPoint = "Registered", trackingDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4), trackingMemo = "" },
            new Tracking() { trackingCode = "DSP", trackingPoint = "Shipped", trackingDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4), trackingMemo = "" },
            new Tracking() { trackingCode = "CCI", trackingPoint = "Cleared", trackingDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4), trackingMemo = "" },
            new Tracking() { trackingCode = "POD", trackingPoint = "Delivered", trackingDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4), trackingMemo = "" }
        }
    }
};
```

I need the query that would check and return only shipment tracking(s) that has trackingCode == "DSP" but not shipment tracking with "CCI" or "POD" trackingCode, so in this example shipment tracking with tracking number 32021001002 would be the one.

I have tried this but doesn't seem to work:

```
foreach (var shipment in shipments)
{
    var foo = shipment.trackings.FirstOrDefault((t => t.trackingCode == "DSP" && t.trackingCode != "CCI"));

    if (shipment.trackings.Contains(foo))
    {
        
    }
}
```

Any help or pointer is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `t.trackingCode == "DSP" && t.trackingCode != "CCI"` - the second predicate is redundant. if TrackingCode equals "DSP" it is automatically not equal to "CCI". You're making a classic mistake of looking (as a human) at values across rows, but writing code that compares values within the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> has trackingCode == "DSP" but not shipment tracking with "CCI" or
> "POD"

I would fill two collections to simplify it and to make it easy to be changed:

```
var validCodes = new List<string>{"DSP"};
var invalidCodes = new List<string>{"CCI", "POD"};
```

If you want to ignore the case, so treat `dsp` and `DSP` same you need [`StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase?view=net-6.0), otherwise `StringComparer.Ordinal`.

The query is pretty simple:

```
List<ShipmentTracking> trackingList = shipments
    .Where(st => st.trackings.Any(t => validCodes.Contains(t.trackingCode, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    .Where(st => !st.trackings.Any(t => invalidCodes.Contains(t.trackingCode, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    .ToList();
```

Instead of two `Where` you can also use one with `&&`. I prefer two because it's easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

You want shipments where  *for the list of trackings: there IS any tracking code "DSP" and there IS NOT any tracking code "CCI"*

```
shipments.Where(s => 
  s.Trackings.Any(t => t.TrackingCode == "DSP") && 
  !s.Trackings.Any(t => t.TrackingCode == "CCI")
);
```

You could also write this as:

```
shipments.Where(s => 
  s.Trackings.Any(t => t.TrackingCode == "DSP") && 
  s.Trackings.All(t => t.TrackingCode != "CCI")
);
```

i.e. *shipments where there is any tracking code that is DSP, and all the tracking codes are not CCI"*

Use whichever makes more sense to you